# drupal: simple form and answer in the same url

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working my way around Drupal API with limited success.

I want to have a URL with a form in it, so that when I "GET" that URL I get the form (have that), when I input a wrong "code" into that form and POST that same URL I get the same form with an error message (have that too), but when I POST that **same URL** with the right "code" I get a different code, no longer displaying the previous form.

No redirects, all the requests (posts and gets) should be targeted to domain.com/entry

This is a code I have (simplified):

```php
function entry_menu() {
    $items['entry'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'entry_handler',
        'access arguments' => array('access entry'),
        type => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function entry_handler() {
    return drupal_get_form('entry_daily_code');
}

function entry_daily_code($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['code'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Code for Today',
    );

    form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Access',
    );

    return $form;
}

function entry_daily_code_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if (isset($form_state['values']['code']) && $form_state['values'] == "1234") {
        drupal_set_message(t('Success'));
    }
    else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Fail'));
    }
}
```

I imagine that what I want to do should happen in "entry_handler".

It needs to know the status returned by the form, and to either return the form, or a different content, but I'm failing at that.

Made a diagram to illustrate my point, in case it wasn't coming across:
[image: diagram]

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validation handler:

```
function entry_daily_code_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['code'] != '1234') {
    form_set_error('code', t('Fail'));
  }
}

function entry_daily_code_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // If you are here, the validation handler already checked
  // that $form_state['values']['code'] == '1234'
  drupal_set_message(t('Success'));

  // Redirect to a different page:
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'entry/success';
}
```

If you don't redirect in the submit handler, Drupal will redirect to the current page according to the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to have a redirect. It needs to be the same URL, but that displays something or another depending on the result of the posted form.

Comment: In a different context I would have a different handler for post or get, get would always get the form; post would either have the form + error message or a different set of content on success. How can achieve that in Drupal?

Comment: Let `entry_daily_code()` decide what to put into the "form" based on the contents of the `$form_state` variable. To prevent redirection, you need to set `$form_state['redirect'] = false` in the submit handler explicitly.

Comment: Mmmh... I see, that could work. But since entry_daily_code is wrapped in a drupal_get_form, shouldn't I return something "form-like"? I read something about "renderable arrays" somewhere... :P

Comment: Render arrays are "form-like". In fact, they are an extension of how forms where defined in Drupal 6.

Comment: I meant, because I'm not sure how to build the render array and how compatible would be with drupal_get_form. The response I need would be a short list of links, some descriptions, etc. Reading this (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) I guess I could just use the "#markup" attribute and put everything in there?

Comment: The `#markup` attribute is indeed the quick and dirty way. However, returning non-Form-API elements from the form callback should also work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39065/discussion-between-yivi-and-oswald)

Comment: Could you give me an example? Or a link to an example? I have no idea on how to build the non-Form-API array elements, and I'm not having a lot of luck going through the docs. And maybe you can put it in your answer, so I can "accept" it? SO doesn't like "extended discussions in comments", apparently.